# how to disable link in table, using jquery or boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td> 
         <td>2</td>
         <td><a href="#">Borrar</a></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using bootstrap and JQuery and I would like to disable my link in the table. I tried:

```
this <tr><td class="disabled"><a href="#">Borrar</td></tr>,
this <tr><td disabled><a href="#">Borrar</td></tr>,
this <tr><td><a href="#" class="disabled">Borrar</td></tr>,
this <tr><td><a href="#" disabled>Borrar</td></tr>
```

But this is not working.

PD: Disable with JQuery or bootstrap is good for me and I don't want to convert the link to button in bootstrap.

Comment: What do you mean by `disabled`? Since you have no valid path in your `href` it's pretty much disabled, or why not remove the `<a>` tags and let just the text be?

Comment: your html is not valid `a` tg is not closed

Comment: Is closed now, i forgot close here but no in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and worked for me.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td> 
         <td>2</td>
         <td><a href="#" class="btn" disabled>Borrar</a></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `preventDefault()` method

```
$('.table').on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //or
    //return false;
});
```

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

you can disable all link click events by this

```
$('a').click(function()
{
     return false;
});
```

.

**[option]**

or if you want to disable only specific link, the first give ID to that link, like:

```
<a href="#" id="lnk">Borrar</a>
```

and change JavaScript part like this:

```
$('#lnk').click(function()
{
     return false;
});
```